# Framework7 Cordova app user interactions problem

Tags: ios, cordova, ionic-framework, frameworks, html-framework-7

I compiled and run app on ios simulator. Firstly i coded and designed everything on chrome then i tried to run on ios app and it look similir but i cant do anything on app. Images loading slowly and cant switch tabs or cant click anywhere. Also i cant scroll down on main page so i cant also switch between tabs.

[image: App screenshot on simulator]

Start of an app like this. and everything working on chrome but not working on simulator(also same at real device)

App console output

```
[Log] Token kontrol ediliyor.
[Log] token kullanılabilir
[Log] page init
[Log] {Result: false, Data: “”}
[Log] [Array, Array, Array, Array, Array, Array, Array, Array, Array] (9)
```

As i said i cant click anywhere on app. Normally on chrome browser(i was testing) i can scroll down to page, changing tabs. Open modal from top-right icon etc. i cant do anything on simulator and there was no errors. I dont know any way to follow to fix that problem. Is anyone heard that before  or any ideas to fix it ?

Answer (score 0):

Problem fixed by changing this line at config.xml

```
<preference name="AutoHideSplashScreen" value="true" />
```

This value was false. Changing it to true fixes the problem.